# Masstransit - The requested service 'MassTransit.Scoping.ScopedConsumeContextProvider' has not been registered after receive interoperability message

Tags: masstransit

I´m upgrading to latest Masstransit version and when trying to publish a raw message json using a minimal message as describe in docs generate the error bellow:
http://masstransit-project.com/architecture/interoperability.html

```
{
    "message": {
        "value": "Some Value",
        "customerId": 27
    },
    "messageType": [
        "urn:message:MassTransit.Tests:ValueMessage"
    ]
}
```

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: No deserializer was registered for the message content type: application/json. Supported content types include application/vnd.masstransit+json, application/vnd.masstransit+bson, application/vnd.masstransit+xml

**Adding the header Content_type application/vnd.masstransit+json and publishing again generates the follow error:**

Content-Type:   application/vnd.masstransit+json
MT-Fault-ConsumerType:  DocumentRouting.API.Consumers.DocumentRoutingConsumer
MT-Fault-ExceptionType: Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException
MT-Fault-Message:   The requested service 'MassTransit.Scoping.ScopedConsumeContextProvider' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
MT-Fault-MessageType:   EventBus.IntegrationEvents.IMessageReceivedIntegrationEvent
MT-Fault-StackTrace:    at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType)
at Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection.AutofacServiceProvider.GetRequiredService(Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.ScopeProviders.InternalScopeExtensions.UpdateScope(IServiceScope scope, ConsumeContext context)
at MassTransit.ExtensionsDependencyInjectionIntegration.ScopeProviders.DependencyInjectionConsumerScopeProvider.MassTransit.Scoping.IConsumerScopeProvider.GetScope[TConsumer,T](ConsumeContext`1 context)
at MassTransit.Scoping.ScopeConsumerFactory`1.Send[TMessage](ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.ConsumerMessageFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<MassTransit.ConsumeContext<TMessage>>.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
at GreenPipes.Filters.TeeFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
at GreenPipes.Filters.OutputPipeFilter`2.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, TOutput pipeContext)
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Filters.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next)
at GreenPipes.Filters.RescueFilter`2.GreenPipes.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next)
```

Environment:
ASP.NET Core 3.1
Masstransit with Autofac Container replacement

```cs
 Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())

Masstransit initialization using Autofac Module:

     protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
            {
               
                builder.AddMassTransit(x =>
                {
                    x.AddConsumer<ConsumerName>();
    
                    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, config) =>
                    {
                      config.Host(new Uri(busSettings.RabbitMQHost), h =>
                      {
                          h.Username(busSettings.Username);
                          h.Password(busSettings.Password);
                       });

                    config.ReceiveEndpoint(busSettings.QueueName, ec =>
                    {
                        ec.Consumer<ConsumerName>(context, cc =>
                        {
```

Comment: I tried to improve the formatting, it would be good if you could take a look at it yourself.

Comment: I'll never forget that Mass Transit incident. New Jack took it too far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems cut off, but you should be using:

```
config.ReceiveEndpoint(busSettings.QueueName, ec =>
{
    ec.ConfigureConsumer<ConsumerName>(context, cc =>
    {
```

There may be other issues/solutions once you add the remainder of the configuration code.

Comment: Hi Chris! Modifying to ConfigureConsumer its worked. Thanks!